Firebase deploy created over 10k changes
I tried to integrate next.js project with firebase. Everything was ok, however when I tried to use firebase hosting, it made over 10k changes. The project itself has only like 28 files (basically this is default project from npm create. What is wrong? I have deployed a small react project and it never made so many changes. At this point I even do not know where to look, all the changes are in .firebase folder

These are temporary files created during the build process - they aren't required to keep and certainly shouldn't be in your repo.
You need to add .firebase folder to "ignore" section in firebase.json
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply
